# vnc : why is xeyes working and not gnome-terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome, vnc

I have a script that opens a vnc connection and then runs an application on the remote machine. When this application is xeyes, everything works perfectly but when it's gnome-terminal, I see no terminal appearing on the screen of the remote machine.

How can I launch a terminal on my remote machine?